# An exhaustion function on a non-empty space must have a minimum value

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $X$ be a topological space, an $exhaustion function$ is a function $h \in C(X, \mathbb{R})$ such that $h^{-1}((- \infty , c])$ is compact for every $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that an exhaustion function on a non-empty space must have a minimum value

Let $A \subset X$, for $a \in A$ such that $h(a) \leq c_1 \in \mathbb{R}$, $a \in h^{-1}((-\infty, c_1])$. As $h^{-1}((-\infty, c])$ is compact, $hh^{-1}((-\infty, c])$ is compact and $hh^{-1}((-\infty, c])$ has a minimum. Let $m_1 = \min\{ hh^{-1}((-\infty, c])\}$. Therefore, for all $a \in A$, $h(a) \geq m_1$. Similarly, for all $c_i \in \mathbb{R}$, $h(a) \geq m_i$.

This is what I have now,but how should I argue that a minimum exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x_0\in X$. We can do this, since $X$ is non-empty. Let $c=h(x_0)$ and let $T=h^{-1}((-\infty,c])$. Note that $T$ is compact by definition of exhaustion function. Note also that $T$ is non-empty, since $x_0\in T$. Since $T$ is compact and $h$ is continuous, $h|_T$ has a minimum value. Let $x_1\in T$ be such that $h(x_1)=\min_{x\in T}h(x)$. In particular, since $x_0\in T$, $h(x_1)\leqslant h(x_0)=c$.

I claim that $h(x_1)$ is not just the minimum of $h$ on $T$, but on all of $X$. Fix $x\in X$.

Case $1$: $x\in T$. Then $h(x_1)\leqslant h(x)$, since $h(x_1)$ is the minimum of $h$ on $T$.

Case $2$: $x\in X\setminus T$. Then since $x\notin T=h^{-1}((-\infty,c])$, $h(x)\in \mathbb{R}\setminus (-\infty,c]$. In other words, $h(x)>c=h(x_0)\geqslant h(x_1)$.